# NextJS logging creates seperate entry for each line

Tags: node.js, logging, next.js

When checking server side logs in GCP Log Explorer, each line in the error is being logged as separate entry. Ideally an error should be logged as a single entry. Couldn't find much on logging in NextJS. Any pointers on how to resolve the issue?

[image]